# Looking for a simple circuit to switch power to IR LED's at night (2A @ 12 volts)

Tags: switches, relay, light, detector

I'm looking for a simple and cheap way to switch power to a few hi-current IR led's at night.  So some sort of photo detector and a solid-state or traditional relay.  Unless there's a single-component device that combines these functions in the same package?  We're talking 1 to 2 amps at 12 volts.

Comment: Thinking a bit outside the question wording - would a light timer similar to [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Century-Plug-Mechanical-Timer-Grounded/dp/B00MVFF59S/) and 120 V (or 240 V) to 12 V AC adapter work, or are you specifically looking for a light-sensor based design and/or one that doesn't rely on mains/timers?

Comment: Simpler than a generic dark detecting sensor circuit? Or a 50 center arduino circuit?

Answer (score 2):

You would need an optical IR blocking filter to view daylight with a Light sensor chip and suppress the IR emitter spectrum then a comparator or transistor switch with the resistor load gain to go below the threshold to trigger the constant current driver to the IR LEDs.

I suggested the inexpensive twilight & dark motion sensor lights may do what you want.  But they do have pulsed IR LEDs and perhaps you can add more. They also have adjustable sensitivity to trigger an AC load. Pulsed IR is easier to detect motion with high gain as it adapts by AGC to any steady reflections and triggers off small changes by amplification set by a trimpot threshold.

A flood of steady IR may reduce the sensitivity of pulsed reflective IR so your requirements need to be refined further perhaps for IR and visible light.